# Testing smartphone application on tablet

Tags: android

I have created a map application for android smart phones and I want it to test on real device.I want to test it on galaxy tab as I don't have android phone to test but when I am running it its UI get destorted. Can anyone suggest how to run it on tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how it's distorted it's tough to say, but you probably need something like:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true"
        />
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml` inside the `manifest` element.

Comment: I want it to run as it run on android phone screen.

Comment: please check the image i have uploaded

Comment: Could you post the .xml layout for this activity?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have read the Android documentation about how to handle [different screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). If not please read it. Because that is the best way to avoid bugs related to UI.

You said that you have upload an image, but I can't see it. If that don't work please give us more information. Sometimes app crashes if you are trying to change the orientation in real devices. Hope you have tackle that problem too.